# Как преобразовать строку '00:00:00' (ч:м:с) в микросекунды, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Помогите пожалуйста обработать значение продолжительности времени для сохранения его потом в БД.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так как минута состоит из 60 секунд и час состоит из 60 минут, то количество секунд, зная часы, минуты, секунды, можно найти по формуле:

```
60 * (60 * часов + минут) + секунд
```

Можно использовать [`functools.reduce()` функцию](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce), чтобы реализовать эту формулу:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> s = '01:02:03'
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: 60*x + y, map(int, s.split(':')))
3723
>>> _ * 1000_000
3723000000
```

Более читаемо в две строчки:

```
hours, minutes, seconds = map(int, s.split(':'))
microseconds = (60 * (60 * hours + minutes) + seconds) * 1000_000
```

Если вы строку из [`datetime.timedelta` объекта](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) получили, то проще напрямую из `timedelta` получить микросекунды:

```
>>> import datetime as DT
>>> str(DT.timedelta(hours=1, minutes=2, seconds=3))
'1:02:03'
>>> DT.timedelta(hours=1, minutes=2, seconds=3) // DT.timedelta(microseconds=1)
3723000000
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь, за развернутый ответ

Answer (score 3):

сплиттим по двоеточию, суммируем с коэффициентами:

```
s = '01:02:03'
secs = sum([a*b for a,b in zip([60*60, 60, 1], map(int,s.split(':')))])
usecs = 1000000*secs
```

Comment: `[]` не нужны. `sum(map(mul, [60*60, 60, 1], map(int,s.split(':'))))`

Answer (score 2):

Считываете первые два знака, пропуская ':' и так далее. 
Потом умножаете все на секунды, суммируете, и переводите в микросекунды

```
a = text[0] + text[1]
b = text[3] + text[4]
C = text[6] + text[7]
a = int(a); b = int(b); c = int(c)
result = ((a*3600) + b*60 + c)*1000000
```